# UIWebView stimulator/app?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, webui

Currently making apps [html5/js] that run through various platforms that make use of UIWebView,
I usually test them in Safari, changing the webagent to iPad but theres always some inconsistencies. Is there anyway to run a stimulator on OSX? [perhaps something like this, http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/webview-application-in-ipad/ ]

is it possible to compile an APP, i.e a small browser or similar that i can test my 'apps' on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install Xcode from the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).
2. Launch Xcode.
3. Open iOS Simulator:
   [image]
4. Select the device of your choice:
   [image]
5. Start Safari and test your website.

Comment: Thanks, i had thought of that, only thing is that the app doesnt show bottom bit because safari bar takes up some space, might have to reduce the ratio in viewport